# Print list in reverse order or put new items before the first

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm starting with AngularJS and Firebase. I'm looking for the way to insert new items in a list (hosted in Firebase) at the top or print the last item of the list at the top.
The filter 'orderBy' from Angular doesn't work for me because it's a list.

My actual code for insert items:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://[here is my instance].firebaseio.com/");
$scope.lineas = [];
angularFire(ref, $scope, "lineas");
$scope.agregarLinea = function() {
   $scope.lineas.push({texto: $scope.linea});
   $scope.linea = "";
};
```

And for list the items:

```
<ul class='lineas'>
    <li ng-repeat="linea in lineas">
        <span>{{linea.texto}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why orderBy doesn't work? Is $scope.lineas an object or an array?

Comment: Sorry @Anant. $scope.lineas is an array. The answer from Jeff Ilse worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you use implicit databinding in angularfire, it returns an object which can't be used in an orderBy in angular. You could use angularFireCollection instead.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://[here is my instance].firebaseio.com/");
$scope.lineas = [];
$scope.lineas = angularFireCollection(ref);
$scope.agregarLinea = function() {
   $scope.lineas.add({texto: $scope.linea});
   $scope.linea = "";
};
```

the id generated by firebase is based on a date, so can be used for sorting:

```
<ul class='lineas'>
    <li ng-repeat="linea in lineas | orderBy:'-$id'">
        <span>{{linea.$id}} - {{linea.texto}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `splice()` function to insert at the beginning of the array

```
$scope.lineas.splice(0, 0, {texto: $scope.linea});
```